# Delegate from different Django app

Tags: django, python-3.x, django-views

Say I have two Django apps, `abc` and `xyz`. The `abc` app is a package that should be installed using `pip3`, and `xyz` is some custom app using features from `abc`.

How can `xyz` provide a delegate method to be used in a view in `abc`? Say `abc` need to send a message, it doesn't care if it should be send via SMS, email or avian carrier, so if `xyz` could provide a delegate method, this method could be called from `abc`, without `abc` caring about the implementation.

Python handles delegates smoothly, but how do I wire it up in a Django view?

I know I can use a message queue or a callback url, but it seems a bit strange to me that there isn't an easier way to do this.

Comment: How about using a signal? https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.8/topics/signals/

Comment: @Claudiu - seems like a good idea to use a custom signal. Looking into it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[Signals](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.8/topics/signals/) can help you achieve what you're looking for.

From Django's documentation on the subject:

> Django includes a “signal dispatcher” which helps allow decoupled applications get notified when actions occur elsewhere in the framework. In a nutshell, signals allow certain senders to notify a set of receivers that some action has taken place. They’re especially useful when many pieces of code may be interested in the same events.

Here are a few other resources on the subject:

- [Using signals in your Django app](http://paltman.com/using-signals-your-django-app/)
- [A simplified explanation](https://coderwall.com/p/ktdb3g/django-signals-an-extremely-simplified-explanation-for-beginners)